# Three20 'Back' button on WebController not functioning

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, navigation, three20

I am using Three20's WebController in my project and I am having issues with the 'back' arrow on the bottom controls (the <| button).

When I load a page and click a link in the WebController you'd expect the back button to enable and if touched bring you back to the original page.

But when I hit a link from the original page the back button is not always working, it stays disabled therefore you cannot go back to the original page.

It does sometimes work, but it seems random and its rare it does. I looked in the source for three20's WebController and all its doing is using a UIWebView's goBack function. But as I said it does work sometimes, but not most of the time.

I have searched the net but found no other reports of this issues, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find my solution. I traced the code and [_webView canGoBack] was returning NO, it was because I was not loading a request, I was rather loading an HTML string which wasn't being saved for use in the back button.

I changed my code back to loading requests and it fixed the issue.

Solution was found here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18870-uiwebview-cangoback-always-returns-no.html